# FreeBSD's ng_nat stopping pass the packets periodically

Tags: freebsd, nat

I have FreeBSD router:

```
#uname
9.1-STABLE FreeBSD 9.1-STABLE #0: Fri Jan 18 16:20:47 YEKT 2013
```

It's a powerful computer with a lot of memory

```
#top -S
last pid: 45076;  load averages:  1.54,  1.46,  1.29                                      up 0+21:13:28  19:23:46
84 processes:  2 running, 81 sleeping, 1 waiting
CPU:  3.1% user,  0.0% nice, 32.1% system,  5.3% interrupt, 59.5% idle
Mem: 390M Active, 1441M Inact, 785M Wired, 799M Buf, 5008M Free
Swap: 8192M Total, 8192M Free

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME   WCPU COMMAND
   11 root          4 155 ki31     0K    64K RUN     3  71.4H 254.83% idle
   13 root          4 -16    -     0K    64K sleep   0 101:52 103.03% ng_queue
    0 root         14 -92    0     0K   224K -       2 229:44 16.55% kernel
   12 root         17 -84    -     0K   272K WAIT    0 213:32 15.67% intr
40228 root          1  22    0 51060K 25084K select  0  20:27  1.66% snmpd
15052 root          1  52    0   104M 22204K select  2   4:36  0.98% mpd5
   19 root          1  16    -     0K    16K syncer  1   0:48  0.20% syncer
```

Its tasks are: NAT via ng_nat and PPPoE server via mpd5.

Traffic  through - about 300Mbit/s, about 40kpps at peak.
Pppoe sessions created - 350 max.

ng_nat is configured by by the script:

```
 /usr/sbin/ngctl -f- <<-EOF                                            

             mkpeer ipfw: nat %s out                                                                               
             name ipfw:%s %s                                                                                       
             connect ipfw: %s: %s in                                                                               
             msg %s: setaliasaddr 1.1.%s
```

There are 20 such ng_nat nodes, with about 150 clients.

Sometimes, the traffic via nat stops. When this happens vmstat reports a lot of FAIL counts

```
vmstat -z | grep -i netgraph
ITEM                   SIZE  LIMIT     USED     FREE      REQ FAIL SLEEP
NetGraph items:          72,  10266,       1,     376,39178965,   0,   0
NetGraph data items:     72,  10266,       9,   10257,2327948820,2131611,4033
```

I was tried increase

```
net.graph.maxdata=10240                                                                                           
net.graph.maxalloc=10240
```

but this doesn't work.

It's a new problem (1-2 week). The configuration had been working well for about 5 months and no configuration changes were made leading up to the problems starting.

In the last few weeks we have slightly increased traffic (from 270 to 300 mbits) and little more pppoe sessions (300->350).

Help me please, how to find and solve my problem?

Upd:
Info about network cards:

```
# pciconf -lv | grep -B3 network   
em0@pci0:0:25:0:        class=0x020000 card=0x35788086 chip=0x15028086 rev=0x05 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82579LM Gigabit Network Connection'
    class      = network
--
em1@pci0:2:0:0: class=0x020000 card=0x35788086 chip=0x10d38086 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82574L Gigabit Network Connection'
    class      = network
```

UPD:
There is 2 "top" output
https://gist.github.com/korjavin/9190181

when I swith net.isr.dispatch to hybrid.
After this, I have tons of mpd processes (don't know why) and one CPU to 100% of interrupt, and after 10 minutes of work it was rebooted, due to big packet lost.

UPD:
Happened again
There is "top" output before reboot and after
https://gist.github.com/korjavin/9254734

looks like problem in ng_queue proccess, which eating CPU to much.
Since my first post, there much more sessions and traffics.
About 400 pppoe , and 450Mbit/s

Comment: Can you post a netstat -m and watch "ipfw -d list | wc" when this is happening?  And ngctl -list ?

Comment: Oh, and what card driver are you using?

Comment: #ipfw -d list | wc -l
      42
# ngctl list | wc -l
    4044
#ngctl types       
There are 25 total types:
car,ether,socket,pppoe about 500 and 32 nat nodes, and I upd post with card info

Comment: You seem to be spending a lot of time processing interrupts, what's 'vmstat -i" give you?

Comment: vmstat : https://gist.github.com/9019910

Comment: This is a fun one.  Do you have 4 ng_queue processes running and that one just sitting on a CPU?

Comment: ps auxww show me only one ng_queue, and in top just now I see 11.72% CPU ng_queue

Comment: Probably, I got a mistake. netstat -Q , show thread count =1. I have net.isr.maxthreads=4 in the sysctl.conf instead of loader.conf, am I get your point? Its a reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try bumping net.link.ifqmaxlen in /boot/loader.conf to 10240.
As I underestand it, the em(4) (and igp, the Intel 10g card) driver (or at least your 82574L) won't balance non-IP traffic (your pppoe) so everything goes in to one ng_queue.

I don't understand why one of your interfaces (em0) is using one IRQ while the other (em1) is using separate IRQs for tx, rx, and link. Are both NIC cards in MSI-X capable slots?

You can probably make more sense of this than I can (I don't know Russian, and Google translate doesn't help much):

http://forum.nag.ru/forum/index.php?s=c4da62052515736f45c73b932216af33&showtopic=82322&st=0

[This thread from the FreeBSD forums has some suggestions](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=33556)

[The FreeBSD wiki on Network Performance Tuning explains a little bit about single-threading in ng_nat and some workarounds](https://wiki.freebsd.org/NetworkPerformanceTuning)

Some people have reported success disabling IPv6 in the kernel (and in mpd) but I don't see any real consensus there.

EDIT:  [I forgot to add this one,](http://dadv.livejournal.com/139170.html?thread=501666), seems to have several other relevant tuning parameters, I thought the dummynet related ones looked promising.

Let me know what happens, this is an interesting problem...

Comment: em1 82574L have not pppoe, its all on em0 only. I know russian, and you links are briliant. I will inform you about all the things.

Comment: Both network cards is internal for motherboard.

Comment: Today this was happened again, and I add net.link.ifqmaxlen=10240 into  loader.conf, also I update the post with info about net.isr

Comment: And again. OMG. I update the post with info

Comment: And again ;( I change network cards to igb. Bot nothing. Will try change entire server.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
deny ip from any to any dst-port 6881 out
```

So, it was about NAT and state count and torrent